# Geany Message Window Cutoff from Screen

Tags: linux, raspbian, geany

I have been using geany for a couple of days now. Today, I logged into my device, launched Geany and noticed the message window is about halfway cutoff.  Thank you in advance! Does anyone have any suggestions?

screen

[image: 1]

No amount of relaunching, rebooting, messing with xterm, or toggling the different sidebars, message windows, and toolbars has been successful.

Comment: Please search before asking questions https://superuser.com/questions/692666/how-to-get-rid-of-this-vertical-line-in-geany

Comment: Hi Andy! Thanks for pointing me in that direction. I did see that post (which was helpful for explaining that line btw!). However, that is different from my question as I am wondering about my window being cutoff at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The following might not work, but there's no harm in trying...

Go to `Edit > Preferences > General section > Startup tab` and, if checked, uncheck "Save window size". Then close and restart Geany and, hopefully, the Geany window will be reasonably sized.